# What is the best way to create a connection in startup in asp.net core webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, smpp

I want to create a SmppClient using JamaaTech Smpp Library. With the client i will create, i want to listen to incoming sms and send the body of the sms to a rabbitmq queue. My problem is :
**How Can i create only one instance of smppclient on the start of my application, and inject it to other service for manipulation.**

Here is how i create my smppclient with jamaatech.

```
private SmppClient CreateSmppClient(ISmppConfiguration config)
    {
        var client = new SmppClient
        {
            Name = config.Name
        };
        //client.SmppEncodingService = new SmppEncodingService(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        client.ConnectionStateChanged += Client_ConnectionStateChanged;
        client.StateChanged += Client_StateChanged;
        client.MessageSent += Client_MessageSent;
        client.MessageDelivered += Client_MessageDelivered;
        client.MessageReceived += Client_MessageReceived;

        var properties = client.Properties;
        properties.SystemID = config.SystemId;// "mysystemid";
        properties.Password = config.Password;// "mypassword";
        properties.Port = config.Port;// 2034; //IP port to use
        properties.Host = config.Host;// "196.23.3.12"; //SMSC host name or IP Address
        properties.SystemType = config.SystemType;// "mysystemtype";
        properties.DefaultServiceType = config.DefaultServiceType;// "mydefaultservicetype";
        properties.DefaultEncoding = config.Encoding;

        //Resume a lost connection after 30 seconds
        client.AutoReconnectDelay = config.AutoReconnectDelay;

        //Send Enquirer Link PDU every 15 seconds
        client.KeepAliveInterval = config.KeepAliveInterval;

        return client;
    }
```

Comment: IMO there is no meaningful way to provide an instance of a statefully connected service via a stateless web api *directly in asp.net*. write a backend service that runs permanently and keeps that connection open; or better: connect just-in-time and disconnect immediately after the request. Unless connecting and disconnecting is disproportionally expensive, this is the usual approach.

Comment: a backend service ? Like the background service on dotnet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Create your own Interface ISmppClient and SmppClient class

2- in startup.cs configure dependencies

```
services.AddSingleton<IMySmppClient , MySmppClient >();
```

3- Inject IMySmppClient by Contructor into the classes where you need it

Comment: I have already done that. It's simple dependency injection with singleton lifetime. I want my application to create an instance of MySmppClient on startup and be able ot use this instance in other class.